# Object Required - error 424 MS ACCESS 2010

Tags: object, ms-access, vba, required

I'm really new at VBA but I have this same code in another database, and now I've just copied the code and paste in another database but I get this Object Required error in the last line.
The code is bigger but I've just stopped on the line where I get the error.

```
 Dim frm As Form, ctl As Control
 Dim varItm As Variant
 Dim stgMO, stgPID, stMail, stgMailCC As String
 Dim Question As Long
 Dim OutApp, OutMail As Object

 Set frm = Forms!Overview
 Set ctl = frm!cl_onboarding

 stgMO = ctl.Column(7)
 stgPID = ctl.Column(2)
 stgMail = ctl.Column(8)
 stgMailCC = ctl.Column(9)

Question = MsgBox("Do you want to send an e-mail containing the codes for this Agent?", vbYesNo, "Send e-mail")
If Question = vbYes Then

    Set OutApp = Outlook.Application
```

Comment: What happens if you change `Set OutApp = Outlook.Application` to `Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a [**Reference**](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/References.htm) in VBA to Outlook.

VBA editor -> menu Tools -> References

Select and check `Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library`

**Edit**: while the above is true, you would probably get a different error if the reference was missing.

The problem may be in this line:

```
Dim OutApp, OutMail As Object
```

which actually gets evaluated as

```
Dim OutApp As Variant, OutMail As Object
```

and should read

```
Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
```

But a Variant can hold an object too, so this may also not be the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

you have `dim stMail` as a variable but then you use `stgMail`. just check your spelling.

You also use `dim question as long`, this confuses me a bit because I thought `long` meant an integer (there are min and max values but I cant remember).

Comment: Well spotted! @joao: please add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module. This doesn't cause the *Object Required* error though. It will cause other problems down the road. -- Long is a 32bit signed Integer.

Comment: Thanks both of you.
Can't believe the mistake was a spelling error. :)